# How Can I connect the emulated device on genymotion on windows with the adb on wsl?

Tags: linux, windows, windows-subsystem-for-linux, adb

I'm trying to setting up an environment to develop in react native.
I've installed the sdk-android, the npm of react native on wsl and the genymotion on windows.
I want to use the vscode on windows and run the project on wsl and emulate on genymotion.

Comment: You may use any Linux distribution instead of using Windows to develop it. ADB, genymotion, VSCode all supports Linux system.